Is the event horizon formed of Bose-Einstein condensate matter?
According to some experiments, when immense pressures are applied to certain materials, new states of matter and unconventional physical laws emerge.
On the early 2000's Lena Hau and her collegues were able to stop light for a moment inside a Bose-Einstein condensate.
According to science, the state of matter inside a black hole, where gravity, mass, and density are infinite, is currently unknown.
According to current theories, time slows down or even stops inside a black hole.
Once past the event horizon, matter, including light, is unable to escape gravity.
Could matter on the event horizon (even as a matemathical surface, not an actual one) be in a Bose-Einstein condensate state, for example, where even light would stop and be unable to continue advancing? (Note the difference between unability of light to escape by gravity effect and 'really' stopping light itself).
The accepted theories relate the slowing down of light speed to the space-time curvature, not to the state of matter itself, but could also have an effect on how we percieve it?
May the Bose-Einstein condensate state be responsible for stopping matter falling in, rather than (or besides) space-time curvature?
May the thermal speed of atoms be related with what we call time? Close to 0°K, atoms can't move, so time doesn't play any role (no change or movement, no reason for time). This would also be coherent with the idea of time stopping inside a black hole, but with a different perspective.

This seems to be more of an off-topic personal speculation than a question about mainstream physics.

It is an interesting idea but no the matter at the event horizon is not a Bose-Einstein condensate.
Observers outside the black hole observe matter to be piling up at the horizon so from their perspective the matter is being compressed at the horizon. However if you were falling into the horizon you would not notice anything special happening at the horizon. Indeed you would fall straight through it without even noticing it was there. You and all the matter around you would be behaving perfectly normally and if you measured the speed of light you'd find it was equal to $c$.
The compression and time dilation observed by the external observer is a result of the spacetime curvature and not due to anything weird happening to the matter at the horizon.
